# Possible to check number of objects in touch location?

Tags: iphone, object, location, uitouch

Is it possible to check number of objects in a certain touch location?
I have tagged all objects with a number, but couldn't think of a way it would work.

Basically what I want to do is add uiimageview to touch point, BUT when there is already an other uiimageview, I would do nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: I have come up with a solution myself...but it's not so elegant. I'm going to add all the positions of objects ever added to the view into an array, and check the new touch location against this. It will probably get choppy when I've a lot of objects...Anyone with better idea, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a good idea to start. All the objects that you add on a view are already kept in an array called `[myview subviews]`. It was a good idea to tag them because then you can easily access them with `[myview viewWithTag: kFirstViewTag]`.

So to answer the second part, when your checking touch locations, check if the touch location intersects with any of your subviews.

For example:

```
for (UIView* view in [myView subviews]) {
   if (CGRectContainsPoint([view frame], touchPoint) {
       //do something
   }
}
```

I can assume you probably don't need to go trough all the subviews, so you can just cycle to ones limited with tags from `kFirstViewTag` to `kLastViewTag` with for loop, like:

```
for (int i = kFirstViewTag; i <= kLastViewTag; i++) {
   UIView *view = [myView viewWithTag: i];
   if (CGRectContainsPoint([view frame], touchPoint) {
       //do something
   }
}
```